# Pre Delete fails with update of Entity CRM2011

Tags: c#, plugins, crm

I'm using a Plugin that should check if some preconditions are true before deleting a entity. If it is false, I throw an `InvaludPluginExecutionException`. This works  very well, but my problem is, that I have one other Plugin that handles the Update of the Entity and, of course some conditions are true, and deleted the linked Entity.
You have to understand that in the Account Entity a List of `AccountGroups` Entity exists. 
The Update Plugin cares about that there is only one `AccountGroup` Entity that is flagged as primary. 
If a add a new `AccountGroup` Entity to the Account, the Plugin deletes the old `AccountGroup` Entity that was flagged as primary and add the new `AccountGroup` Entity as primary.
In this case, the Update Plugin fires the Pre Delete Plugin and cancels the delete step.
Further the `InvalidExecutionException` is thrown.

Are there any ways to find out where the Plugin is fires? E.g. the Update Plugin fires the Delete Call, No Pre Delete Plugin should be executed? Or are there any other ways?

Code of Pre Delete Plugin:

```
[OnPreDelete]
public void PreventDeletion(IServiceProvider serviceProvider){

    var pluginServiceFactory = new PluginServiceFactory(serviceProvider);
    var targetAccount = pluginServiceFactory.Context.GetTargetEntityReference();



    using (var context = new DataContext(pluginServiceFactory.OrganizationService))
    {
        var acgr = (from ac in context.im_customergroupSet
                  where ac.Id == targetAccount.Id
                  select ac).FirstOrDefault();


        if (acgr.im_Primary == true)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Primary Account Groups can not be deleted!");
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to resolve this by passing data between plugins using the SharedVariables collection, see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328579.aspx). I believe this should make it possible for your Update plugin to add some flag into the SharedVariables that the delete plugin can read, then you can drive your logic from that (e.g. don't stop the deletion of the record if the flag is set).

Comment: I Solved the Problem by using the context.depth property. This is to prevent recursive calls in crm plugins.

Comment: O right, I didnt understand that was the problem from your original question.